# Textfield Clearing String

Tags: java, jtextfield, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a program that when the user clicks the box the message will  clear up. **(Must be 6-15 characters)** This thing will clear up when it will be clicked, I Tried using a mouse listener but it doesn't go when i click it.

Here's a snippet of the code :

```
    abc = new JTextField(" (Must be 6-15 characters)");         
    abc.setBounds(40,130,310,30);
    abc.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.ITALIC, 14));
    abc.setForeground(Color.gray);                          
    abc.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        abc.setText("");
      }
    });
    mainPanel.add(abc);
```

Comment: It works fine with me. have you declared `abc` as `final`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks good. Be sure to `@Override` the `mouseClicked` method and declare `abc` as `final`.

```
    final JTextField abc = new JTextField(" (Must be 6-15 characters)");         
    abc.setBounds(40,130,310,30);
    abc.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.ITALIC, 14));
    abc.setForeground(Color.gray);                          
    abc.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            abc.setText("");
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(abc);
```

Comment: It worked. i did not think about using final because i was using the variable abc multiple times so i made a separate one.

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you mark this answer as correct and maybe give it an upvote? :)

Comment: Also how can i NOT clear what they stored in the field, For example the user switches to another box it will clear up when he clicks it. How can i implement this method for once only?